# Call an internal function of a jQuery plugin? Or how to ignore callback calls from a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Edit

Is it possible to call an internal function of a jQuery plugin?

I need to call the *updateColor* function of a [color picker slider](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-colorpickersliders/) but not the *onchange* callback that it triggers.

I could use `$('#colorpicker').trigger("colorpickersliders.updateColor",color)` but that would not call *updateColor* immediately.

If I could call the *updateColor* function directly I could unset the *onchange* callback before the call and reset it after:

```
$('#colorpicker').ColorPickerSliders(onchange:function(){}) // disable my *onchange* callback
// --- a trick to call updateColor immediately --- //
$('#colorpicker').ColorPickerSliders(onchange:MyNormalOnChangeCallback) // enable my *onchange* callback
```

#### Original question

I use [color picker slider](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-colorpickersliders/), it is a jQuery plugin. I set the *onchange* callback function to react to changes.

The problem is that when I want to programmatically change the value of the color, I want to avoid the callback to be called.

I can have a flag (or even a counter) to ignore the calls of my *onchange* callback, but I don't really like this method.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mMNRpSe8X1waWKq8yeSA?p=preview) is a plunkr to illustrate my problem:

```
  var solution1 = false;   // set this to true for the dirty solution
  var ignoreCounter = 0;

  // the onchange callback
  onchange = function(container, color) {
    // I would like to print the color only if it was set manually by the user, not programatically

    if(solution1 && ignoreCounter>0)    // dirty solution: ignore the call if ignoreCounter is greater than 0
    {
      ignoreCounter--;
      return;
    }

    console.log("color: " + color.tiny.toRgbString());
  }

  // initialize ColorPickerSliders
  $('#colorpicker').ColorPickerSliders( { onchange: onchange, flat: true } )

  // set the color programmatically
  setInterval(function(){
    ignoreCounter++; // ignore callback next time
    $('#colorpicker').trigger("colorpickersliders.updateColor", "rgb(0,0,"+(Math.random()*255)+")");
  }, 1000)
```

What would you do? Is there a way to modify a jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The natural callback on a event is prevented when the personnal event function return false.

```
var onchange = function(container, color) {

    if(solution1 && ignoreCounter>0),{
      ignoreCounter--;
      return false;
    }

    console.log("color: " + color.tiny.toRgbString());

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I am looking for: I would like to ignore my own custom onchange callback.